# global unignore does not overrule local ignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Say you're in a git repository with a local *.gitignore* that ignores a file that you would like to unignore with a global *.gitignore*.

Local .gitignore:

```
*.foo
```

Global .gitignore_global:

```
!*.foo
```

It seems that git lets the local ignore "overrule" the unignore in the global gitignore. So, how do you unignore a file that has an ignore rule in a local *.gitignore*?

Comment: why can't you change local .gitignore file?

Comment: @uDaY Assume that the team agrees to ignore something, but you don't want to, locally.

Comment: Your team will not be happy if you push a file that was previously ignored.

Comment: @madhead I didn't say that was the intent.

Comment: You can add ignored file to the index manually: `git add -f path/to/ignored/file.foo`

Comment: @madhead I don't want to add an ignored file. I just don't want it ignored.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Do you want the file to be an eyesore in every `git status` and don't commit it?

Comment: @madhead When I generate .patch files, I like to see the noise, send the patches, and then delete them. So yes, I want *git status* to tell me what's up. [An example scenario is here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2015-04/msg03571.html)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that git lets the local ignore "overrule" the unignore in the global gitignore.

You can confirm it with [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile.foo
```

The [gitignore man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) defines a specific order:

> Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern.
>   When deciding whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (**within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern decides the outcome**):

In your case, the local `.gitignore` would always have precedence over the global one.